# Regex get ID from URL

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract `ID123` from these given url strings?

```
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html/
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html?bla=123&some=456
```

And if not `ID`, a random string of length equal to `2 (AB, EF, GH, ...)`

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: +1 I prefer URI parsing over Regex parsing when it comes to, well, URI's.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
(?!-)(ID[0-9]*)(?=\.)
```

Tested:
http://regex101.com/r/rP0vI2

If not "ID", then it would be:

```
(?!-)([A-Z]{2}[0-9]*)(?=\.)
```

Tested: http://regex101.com/r/dW8qK0

Comment: if not ID, a random string of length equal to 2 (AB, EF, GH, ...), what is regex?

Answer (score 0):

`$zeichenkette = "my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html";
$suchmuster = '/ID[0-9]{3}/';
preg_match($suchmuster, $zeichenkette, $treffer, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($treffer);`

should print ID123.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=product-)ID[0-9]+(?=\.html)
```

- `(?<=product-)` Positive Lookbehind - Asserts that the ID is preceded by the string `product-`
- `ID` matches the characters ID literally
- `[0-9]+` matches a sequence of digits
- `(?=\.html)` Positive Lookahead - Asserts that the ID is followed by `.html`

Answer (score 0):

Short and effective:

```
<?php
$links = <<< LOB
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html/
my-domain/product/name-product-ID123.html?bla=123&some=456
LOB;

preg_match_all('/-(ID\d+)\./',$links ,$ids, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids[1]); $i++) {
    echo $ids[1][$i]."\n";
}
/*
ID123
ID123
ID123
*/
?>
```

***LIVE DEMO:***
http://ideone.com/OqhL6b

***Explanation:***

```
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(ID\d+)»
   Match the characters “ID” literally «ID»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
```